# How to find value and key from Object and find only keys that have an F with them will return the value of all keys

Tags: javascript, object, filter

```
[
  {
    _id: 223454553,
    "formhub/uuid": "4995281cb95f412f9feb0780d111e2c1",
    start: "2023-03-07T15:36:49.045+06:00",
    end: "2023-03-07T15:37:53.319+06:00",
    today: "2023-03-07",
    "g00/data_id": "cc731edf",
    "g00/mo_name": "04_Md Mohsin Alam_01710231447",
    "g00/date": "2023-03-07",
    "g00/division": "Khulna",
    "g00/district": "Khulna",
    "g00/upazila": "Dighalia",
    "g00/branch": "Dhaka",
    "g00/programe": "WASH",
    "g01/SH002": "No",
    "g01/SH002F": "Height of plinth is less than 6 inch (0.5 ft/15 cm)",
    "g01/SH003": "No",
    "g01/SH003F":
      "the footings/RCC posts are not 2ft (24 inches/60cm) under the ground, not securely anchored",
    "g01/SH004": "No",
    "g01/SH004F":
      "Distance between bamboo columns are more than 5ft (60 inches/152cm)",
    "g01/SH005": "Yes",
    "g01/SH006": "Yes",
    "g01/SH007": "Yes",
    "g01/SH008": "Yes",
    "g01/SH009": "Yes",
    "g01/SH010": "Yes",
    "g01/SH011": "Yes",
    "g01/SH012": "Yes",
    "g01/SH013": "Yes",
    "g01/SH014": "Yes",
    "g01/SH015": "Yes",
    "g01/SH016": "Yes",
    "g01/SH017": "Yes",
    "g01/SH018": "No",
    "g01/SH018F": "The shelter does not have any garenja?",
    "g01/SH019": "NA",
    "g01/SH020": "No",
    "g01/SH020F":
      "The shelter is not tied down in accordance with Sector guidance",
    "g01/SH021": "Yes",
    "g01/SH022": "Yes",
    "g01/SH023": "Yes",
    "g01/SH024": "Yes",
    "g02/SH028": "Yes",
    "g02/SH029": "Yes",
    "g02/SH030": "Yes",
    "g02/SH031": "No",
    "g02/SH031F": "The borak bamboo short beam is not 1.5m C/C",
    "g02/SH032": "Yes",
    "g02/SH033": "Yes",
    "g02/SH034": "Yes",
    "g02/SH035": "Yes",
    "g02/SH036": "Yes",
    "g03/SH037": "Yes",
    "g03/SH038": "No",
    "g03/SH038F": "drum sheet/bamboo fencing does not placed firmly?",
    "g03/SH039": "Yes",
    "g03/SH040": "Yes",
    "g03/SH041": "Yes",
    "g04/SH042": "Yes",
    "g04/SH043": "No",
    "g04/SH043F": "Borak Bamboo Vertical post is not 1000mm from GL",
    "g04/SH044": "No",
    "g04/SH044F": "The railing is not installed firmly",
    "g04/SH045": "No",
    "g04/SH045F": "The GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly",
    version: "v7MxHpbincoNVU4E78xQsv",
    "meta/instanceID": "uuid:94070ff0-465e-481b-bdee-b8abc267839b",
    _xform_id_string: "a3YrJ4shuWDtXUPGUyM5mY",
    _uuid: "94070ff0-465e-481b-bdee-b8abc267839b",
    _attachments: [],
    _status: "submitted_via_web",
    _geolocation: [null, null],
    _submission_time: "2023-03-07T09:38:19",
    _tags: [],
    _notes: [],
    _validation_status: {},
    _submitted_by: null,
  },
  {
    _id: 223454806,
    "formhub/uuid": "4995281cb95f412f9feb0780d111e2c1",
    start: "2023-03-07T15:38:06.252+06:00",
    end: "2023-03-07T15:39:17.615+06:00",
    today: "2023-03-07",
    "g00/data_id": "ec9b782c",
    "g00/mo_name": "06_Md. Jahirul Islam_01711584248",
    "g00/date": "2023-03-09",
    "g00/division": "Chattogram",
    "g00/district": "Brahamanbaria",
    "g00/upazila": "Bijoynagar",
    "g00/branch": "Badda",
    "g00/programe": "WASH",
    "g01/SH002": "No",
    "g01/SH002F": "Height of plinth is less than 6 inch (0.5 ft/15 cm)",
    "g01/SH003": "No",
    "g01/SH003F":
      "the footings/RCC posts are not 2ft (24 inches/60cm) under the ground, not securely anchored",
    "g01/SH004": "Yes",
    "g01/SH005": "Yes",
    "g01/SH006": "Yes",
    "g01/SH007": "Yes",
    "g01/SH008": "Yes",
    "g01/SH009": "Yes",
    "g01/SH010": "Yes",
    "g01/SH011": "Yes",
    "g01/SH012": "Yes",
    "g01/SH013": "Yes",
    "g01/SH014": "Yes",
    "g01/SH015": "Yes",
    "g01/SH016": "Yes",
    "g01/SH017": "Yes",
    "g01/SH018": "Yes",
    "g01/SH019": "No",
    "g01/SH019F": "The shelter do not have any windows?",
    "g01/SH020": "No",
    "g01/SH020F":
      "The shelter is not tied down in accordance with Sector guidance",
    "g01/SH021": "No",
    "g01/SH021F":
      "Despite the zig-zag roof, gutters are not installed between the roofs of adjacent shelters",
    "g01/SH022": "Yes",
    "g01/SH023": "Yes",
    "g01/SH024": "Yes",
    "g02/SH028": "Yes",
    "g02/SH029": "No",
    "g02/SH029F": "The Borak Bamboo short post is not 1.5m C/C",
    "g02/SH030": "Yes",
    "g02/SH031": "Yes",
    "g02/SH032": "Yes",
    "g02/SH033": "Yes",
    "g02/SH034": "Yes",
    "g02/SH035": "Yes",
    "g02/SH036": "No",
    "g02/SH036F": "The GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly",
    "g03/SH037": "No",
    "g03/SH037F": "Borak Bamboo Vertical post is not 500mm C/C",
    "g03/SH038": "No",
    "g03/SH038F": "drum sheet/bamboo fencing does not placed firmly?",
    "g03/SH039": "No",
    "g03/SH039F": "the 1/2 Split of borak bamboo bracing is not 450mm C/C",
    "g03/SH040": "No",
    "g03/SH040F": "the top copping is not installed firmly",
    "g03/SH041": "No",
    "g03/SH041F": "GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly",
    "g04/SH042": "Yes",
    "g04/SH043": "No",
    "g04/SH043F": "Borak Bamboo Vertical post is not 1000mm from GL",
    "g04/SH044": "No",
    "g04/SH044F": "The railing is not installed firmly",
    "g04/SH045": "No",
    "g04/SH045F": "The GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly",
    version: "v7MxHpbincoNVU4E78xQsv",
    "meta/instanceID": "uuid:6d181c9c-f420-4025-a4ba-68013da634ae",
    _xform_id_string: "a3YrJ4shuWDtXUPGUyM5mY",
    _uuid: "6d181c9c-f420-4025-a4ba-68013da634ae",
    _attachments: [],
    _status: "submitted_via_web",
    _geolocation: [null, null],
    _submission_time: "2023-03-07T09:39:14",
    _tags: [],
    _notes: [],
    _validation_status: {},
    _submitted_by: null,
  },
];
```

**I want print only value that keys with "F"

Like below the key and value. print only value**

```
'g01/SH002F': 'Height of plinth is less than 6 inch (0.5 ft/15 cm)',
'g01/SH003F': 'the footings/RCC posts are not 2ft (24 inches/60cm) under the ground, not securely anchored',
'g01/SH019F': 'The shelter do not have any windows?',
'g01/SH020F': 'The shelter is not tied down in accordance with Sector guidance',
'g01/SH021F': 'Despite the zig-zag roof, gutters are not installed between the roofs of adjacent shelters',
'g02/SH029F': 'The Borak Bamboo short post is not 1.5m C/C',
'g02/SH036F': 'The GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly',
'g03/SH037F': 'Borak Bamboo Vertical post is not 500mm C/C',
'g03/SH038F': 'drum sheet/bamboo fencing does not placed firmly?',
'g03/SH039F': 'the 1/2 Split of borak bamboo bracing is not 450mm C/C',
'g03/SH040F': 'the top copping is not installed firmly',
'g03/SH041F': 'GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly',
'g04/SH043F': 'Borak Bamboo Vertical post is not 1000mm from GL',
'g04/SH044F': 'The railing is not installed firmly',
'g04/SH045F': 'The GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly',
const dataFlt = finds.results;
console.log(dataFlt);
const dataFilter = Object.entries(dataFlt).filter(([key, value]) => {
  if (key.length >= 10 && key.includes("F")) return value;
});

console.log(dataFilter);
// I want value here
```

Comment: please use a smaller data set for the question. and apply some formatting to it.

Answer (score -1):

You were close

You need to loop the data. Then you can filter and then map OR use reduce

I use flatmap to flatten the arrays returned

```js
const dataFilter = data.flatMap(dataFlt => Object.entries(dataFlt)
  .filter(([key, value]) => key.length >= 10 && key.includes("F"))
  .map(([_,value]) => value));


console.log(dataFilter);
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
  {
    _id: 223454553,
    "formhub/uuid": "4995281cb95f412f9feb0780d111e2c1",
    start: "2023-03-07T15:36:49.045+06:00",
    end: "2023-03-07T15:37:53.319+06:00",
    today: "2023-03-07",
    "g00/data_id": "cc731edf",
    "g00/mo_name": "04_Md Mohsin Alam_01710231447",
    "g00/date": "2023-03-07",
    "g00/division": "Khulna",
    "g00/district": "Khulna",
    "g00/upazila": "Dighalia",
    "g00/branch": "Dhaka",
    "g00/programe": "WASH",
    "g01/SH002": "No",
    "g01/SH002F": "Height of plinth is less than 6 inch (0.5 ft/15 cm)",
    "g01/SH003": "No",
    "g01/SH003F":
      "the footings/RCC posts are not 2ft (24 inches/60cm) under the ground, not securely anchored",
    "g01/SH004": "No",
    "g01/SH004F":
      "Distance between bamboo columns are more than 5ft (60 inches/152cm)",
    "g01/SH005": "Yes",
    "g01/SH006": "Yes",
    "g01/SH007": "Yes",
    "g01/SH008": "Yes",
    "g01/SH009": "Yes",
    "g01/SH010": "Yes",
    "g01/SH011": "Yes",
    "g01/SH012": "Yes",
    "g01/SH013": "Yes",
    "g01/SH014": "Yes",
    "g01/SH015": "Yes",
    "g01/SH016": "Yes",
    "g01/SH017": "Yes",
    "g01/SH018": "No",
    "g01/SH018F": "The shelter does not have any garenja?",
    "g01/SH019": "NA",
    "g01/SH020": "No",
    "g01/SH020F":
      "The shelter is not tied down in accordance with Sector guidance",
    "g01/SH021": "Yes",
    "g01/SH022": "Yes",
    "g01/SH023": "Yes",
    "g01/SH024": "Yes",
    "g02/SH028": "Yes",
    "g02/SH029": "Yes",
    "g02/SH030": "Yes",
    "g02/SH031": "No",
    "g02/SH031F": "The borak bamboo short beam is not 1.5m C/C",
    "g02/SH032": "Yes",
    "g02/SH033": "Yes",
    "g02/SH034": "Yes",
    "g02/SH035": "Yes",
    "g02/SH036": "Yes",
    "g03/SH037": "Yes",
    "g03/SH038": "No",
    "g03/SH038F": "drum sheet/bamboo fencing does not placed firmly?",
    "g03/SH039": "Yes",
    "g03/SH040": "Yes",
    "g03/SH041": "Yes",
    "g04/SH042": "Yes",
    "g04/SH043": "No",
    "g04/SH043F": "Borak Bamboo Vertical post is not 1000mm from GL",
    "g04/SH044": "No",
    "g04/SH044F": "The railing is not installed firmly",
    "g04/SH045": "No",
    "g04/SH045F": "The GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly",
    version: "v7MxHpbincoNVU4E78xQsv",
    "meta/instanceID": "uuid:94070ff0-465e-481b-bdee-b8abc267839b",
    _xform_id_string: "a3YrJ4shuWDtXUPGUyM5mY",
    _uuid: "94070ff0-465e-481b-bdee-b8abc267839b",
    _attachments: [],
    _status: "submitted_via_web",
    _geolocation: [null, null],
    _submission_time: "2023-03-07T09:38:19",
    _tags: [],
    _notes: [],
    _validation_status: {},
    _submitted_by: null,
  },
  {
    _id: 223454806,
    "formhub/uuid": "4995281cb95f412f9feb0780d111e2c1",
    start: "2023-03-07T15:38:06.252+06:00",
    end: "2023-03-07T15:39:17.615+06:00",
    today: "2023-03-07",
    "g00/data_id": "ec9b782c",
    "g00/mo_name": "06_Md. Jahirul Islam_01711584248",
    "g00/date": "2023-03-09",
    "g00/division": "Chattogram",
    "g00/district": "Brahamanbaria",
    "g00/upazila": "Bijoynagar",
    "g00/branch": "Badda",
    "g00/programe": "WASH",
    "g01/SH002": "No",
    "g01/SH002F": "Height of plinth is less than 6 inch (0.5 ft/15 cm)",
    "g01/SH003": "No",
    "g01/SH003F":
      "the footings/RCC posts are not 2ft (24 inches/60cm) under the ground, not securely anchored",
    "g01/SH004": "Yes",
    "g01/SH005": "Yes",
    "g01/SH006": "Yes",
    "g01/SH007": "Yes",
    "g01/SH008": "Yes",
    "g01/SH009": "Yes",
    "g01/SH010": "Yes",
    "g01/SH011": "Yes",
    "g01/SH012": "Yes",
    "g01/SH013": "Yes",
    "g01/SH014": "Yes",
    "g01/SH015": "Yes",
    "g01/SH016": "Yes",
    "g01/SH017": "Yes",
    "g01/SH018": "Yes",
    "g01/SH019": "No",
    "g01/SH019F": "The shelter do not have any windows?",
    "g01/SH020": "No",
    "g01/SH020F":
      "The shelter is not tied down in accordance with Sector guidance",
    "g01/SH021": "No",
    "g01/SH021F":
      "Despite the zig-zag roof, gutters are not installed between the roofs of adjacent shelters",
    "g01/SH022": "Yes",
    "g01/SH023": "Yes",
    "g01/SH024": "Yes",
    "g02/SH028": "Yes",
    "g02/SH029": "No",
    "g02/SH029F": "The Borak Bamboo short post is not 1.5m C/C",
    "g02/SH030": "Yes",
    "g02/SH031": "Yes",
    "g02/SH032": "Yes",
    "g02/SH033": "Yes",
    "g02/SH034": "Yes",
    "g02/SH035": "Yes",
    "g02/SH036": "No",
    "g02/SH036F": "The GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly",
    "g03/SH037": "No",
    "g03/SH037F": "Borak Bamboo Vertical post is not 500mm C/C",
    "g03/SH038": "No",
    "g03/SH038F": "drum sheet/bamboo fencing does not placed firmly?",
    "g03/SH039": "No",
    "g03/SH039F": "the 1/2 Split of borak bamboo bracing is not 450mm C/C",
    "g03/SH040": "No",
    "g03/SH040F": "the top copping is not installed firmly",
    "g03/SH041": "No",
    "g03/SH041F": "GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly",
    "g04/SH042": "Yes",
    "g04/SH043": "No",
    "g04/SH043F": "Borak Bamboo Vertical post is not 1000mm from GL",
    "g04/SH044": "No",
    "g04/SH044F": "The railing is not installed firmly",
    "g04/SH045": "No",
    "g04/SH045F": "The GI Wire/Rope is not installed tightly",
    version: "v7MxHpbincoNVU4E78xQsv",
    "meta/instanceID": "uuid:6d181c9c-f420-4025-a4ba-68013da634ae",
    _xform_id_string: "a3YrJ4shuWDtXUPGUyM5mY",
    _uuid: "6d181c9c-f420-4025-a4ba-68013da634ae",
    _attachments: [],
    _status: "submitted_via_web",
    _geolocation: [null, null],
    _submission_time: "2023-03-07T09:39:14",
    _tags: [],
    _notes: [],
    _validation_status: {},
    _submitted_by: null,
  },
];
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Map over the array.  Each element needs to be transformed into a new object with just the wanted keys/values.

```
const result = dataflt.map(item =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item)
      .filter(([key, value]) => key.length >= 10 && key.includes("F"))
  )
);
```

Comment: That gives a nested object array. Not just an array of values

Comment: @mplungjan I don’t see that as a requirement.

Comment: `**I want print only value that keys with "F" Like below the key and value. print only value**`